# How can i add $(document).ready(function(){}) after a function in java script

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I want to do is I have a code like below :

```
$(document).ready(
  function(){
   var currentPage = window.location.pathname;
   $('#main-menu-list').find('a[href^="' + currentPage + '"]').closest('li').addClass('active');
  }  
)
```

And now I want to add this code to add and get work with other code. I need to add this code after this one:

```
function () {
    /* If there are forms, make all the submit buttons in the page appear
       disabled and prevent them to be submitted again to avoid accidental
       double clicking. See Issue 980. */
    jQuery(function() {
        /* Delegate the function to document so it's likely to be the last event
           in the queue because of event bubbling. */
        jQuery(document).delegate("form", "submit", function (e) {
            var form = jQuery(this);
            if (form.hasClass("form_disabled")) {
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
            else {
                form
                  .addClass("form_disabled")
                  .find(":submit")
                    .addClass("disabled");
            }
            // Reactivate the forms and their buttons after 3 secs as a fallback.
            setTimeout(function () {
                form
                  .removeClass("form_disabled")
                  .find(":submit")
                    .removeClass("disabled");
            }, 3000);
        });
    });
}
```

How can I get this done. Please help me out to solve this problem.

Comment: What does the function do? When do you want to run it? Would it not be helpful if you run the function in a `.click` (for example) event?

Answer (score 0):

You can create `document.ready()` anywhere in script. It is not necessary all of your code should be in ready function.

You can create instance variable for function and call it where you need:

```
$(document).ready(
  var myFunc = function(){
   var currentPage = window.location.pathname;
   //other code
  }  
  ...
 //and invoke it where you need
  myFunc();
)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, name the long function in your code section, for example, **launchFormControls()**. And then define the function outside of the document ready event. A good practice would be to do so and keep the ready event body clean.

For example:

```
function launchFormControls() {
   //function code
}
```

Or, in other syntax:

```
var launchFormControls = function() {
   //function code
}
```

Second, call your function from within the document ready event. Your function will be defined and able to call once the document is loaded. This code can be placed at the top or bottom of your javascript section or file.

For example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var currentPage = window.location.pathname;
  $('#main-menu-list').find('a[href^="' + currentPage+'"]').closest('li').addClass('active');

  launchFormControls();
});
```